# Can we see the Send nodes and the Receive nodes in the tensorflow GraphDef?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Can we see the *Send* nodes and the *Receive* nodes in the tensorflow GraphDef, or by using python API?

I try the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    x = tf.constant(1.0)
with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
    y = tf.constant(2.0)
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    sum = tf.add(x, y)

graph_def = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
print(graph_def)
```

But there is no send/recv nodes in the `graph_def`. Are there any send/recv nodes added to the graph for transporting `x` and `y` to *cpu*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The send and recv nodes are only added to the graph on the first time you try to execute the graph, in a call to [`tf.Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run)... and, indeed, the set of send and recv nodes that gets added will depend on the specific tensors that you feed and fetch in that call.

You can see the exact graphs that execute on each device, including the send and recv nodes, by passing `tf.RunOptions(output_partition_graphs=True)` to the `Session.run()` call, as follows:

```
options = tf.RunOptions(output_partition_graphs=True)
metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

sess.run(..., options=options, metadata=metadata)

for partition_graph_def in metadata.partition_graphs:
    print partition_graph_def  # Contains all the nodes that ran on a single device.
```

Comment: if it's distributed configuration, how do these two nodes passing tensor? by gRPC? thx

Comment: Yes, the default transport between machines in a distributed setting uses gRPC to transfer the tensor content. However, other transports are available, including MPI and RDMA verbs. The architecture doc here has a high-level overview of how this works: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/architecture#worker_service

Comment: thx a lot! I'm now digging into the detail of how distributed TensorFlow pass protobuf information at runtime, what's the difference between `rendezvous_mgr`, `rpc_rendezvous_mgr`  and `base_rendezvous_mgr` ?

Comment: There's some discussion in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40711279/3574081), but really that's too large a question to handle in a 600-character comment!

Comment: If this is not a proper way to discuss here, please let me know. But still greatly appreciated!

Comment: Got it, I just saw that several days ago. I will dig into the code. Thx!