# Specify gpu in Tensorflow code: /gpu:0 is always working?

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

I have 3 graphics cards in my workstation, one of them is Quadro K620, and the other two are Titan X. Now I would like to run my tensorflow code in one of the graphics card, so that I can leave the others idle for another task.

However, regardless of setting `tf.device('/gpu:0')` or `tf.device('/gpu:1')`, I found the 1st Titan X graphics card is always working, I don't know why.

```
import argparse
import os
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import cv2

from Dataset import Dataset
from Net import Net

FLAGS = None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--foldername', type=str, default='./data-large/')
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', type=int, default=100)
    parser.add_argument('--num_epoches', type=int, default=100)
    parser.add_argument('--learning_rate', type=float, default=0.5)

    FLAGS = parser.parse_args()
    net = Net(FLAGS.batch_size, FLAGS.learning_rate)

    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        # Dataset is a class for encapsulate the input pipeline
        dataset = Dataset(foldername=FLAGS.foldername,
                              batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
                              num_epoches=FLAGS.num_epoches)

        images, labels = dataset.samples_train

        ## The following code defines the network and train
        with tf.device('/gpu:0'): # <==== THIS LINE
            logits = net.inference(images)
            loss = net.loss(logits, labels)
            train_op = net.training(loss)

            init_op = tf.group(tf.initialize_all_variables(), tf.initialize_local_variables())
            sess = tf.Session()
            sess.run(init_op)
            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
            start_time = time.time()
            try:
                step = 0
                while not coord.should_stop():
                    _, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])
                    step = step + 1
                    if step % 100 == 0:
                        format_str = ('step %d, loss = %.2f, time: %.2f seconds')
                        print(format_str % (step, loss_value, (time.time() - start_time)))
                        start_time = time.time()
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                print('done')
            finally:
                coord.request_stop()

            coord.join(threads)
            sess.close()
```

Regarding to the line "`<=== THIS LINE`:"

If I set `tf.device('/gpu:0')`, the monitor says:

```
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K620         Off  | 0000:03:00.0      On |                  N/A |
| 34%   45C    P0     2W /  30W |    404MiB /  1993MiB |      5%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:04:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   39C    P2   100W / 250W |  11691MiB / 12206MiB |      8%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:81:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   43C    P2    71W / 250W |    111MiB / 12206MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

showing the 1st Titan X card is working.

If I set `tf.device('/gpu:1')`, the monitor says:

```
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro K620         Off  | 0000:03:00.0      On |                  N/A |
| 34%   45C    P0     2W /  30W |    411MiB /  1993MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:04:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   52C    P2    73W / 250W |  11628MiB / 12206MiB |     12%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce GTX TIT...  Off  | 0000:81:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| 22%   42C    P2    71W / 250W |  11628MiB / 12206MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

showing that the two Titan X cards are working, not the 2nd Titan X alone.

So any reason behind this and how to specify the gpu I want my program to run in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but the default behavior for a [`tf.train.Optimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#optimizers) object (which I expect is created in `net.training(loss)`) when you call [`minimize()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.minimize) is `colocate_gradients_with_ops=False`. This may lead to the backpropagation ops being placed on the default device, which will be `/gpu:0`.

To work out if this is happening, you can iterate over `sess.graph_def` and look for nodes that either have `/gpu:0` in the `NodeDef.device` field, or have an empty `device` field (in which case they will be placed on `/gpu:0` by default).

Another option for checking what devices are being used is to use the [`output_partition_graphs=True` option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40368563/3574081) when running your step. This shows what devices TensorFlow is actually using (instead of, in `sess.graph_def`, what devices your program is requesting), and should show exactly what nodes are running on `/gpu:0`.

Comment: I printed out sess.graph_def, and found indeed there are nodes without device information. These nodes are about input, which should be created before the code `with tf.device('/gpu:0')`. However, I cannot involve the two lines of code before `with tf.device('/gpu:0')` into the block, because it contains operations about shuffling the FIFOqueue, which seems to work in CPU only. So how can I fully map the whole program into a specified gpu?

Comment: One possible option is to extend the `with tf.device('/gpu:1'):` block around the dataset-creation code, and add the following option when creating your session: `tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True))`. This will enable TensorFlow to move any CPU-only ops back to the CPU, while placing everything else on GPU 1.