# Tensorflow Cross Device Communication

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

As the tensorflow paper states, Tensorflow' cross-device communication is achieved by adding "receive node" and "send node" into devices.

From my understanding, the device(Please considering only CPU devices are involved) is responsible for performing the computation of an operation. However,the data(ex:Tensor produced from an operation, Variable buffer) resides in memory. I don't know how data transfer from one device to another device is achieved **physically**. I guess the data transfer is achieved by shared memory. Is that right?

I will appreciate any explanation/corresponding codes regarding how the data transfer is achieved.
PS: [TensorFlow paper link](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf), Figure 4 shows the cross-device communication mechanism.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In TensorFlow, cross-device communication is achieved using the [`Rendezvous`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41285cf7a11fa3a2c2ead6b6e9adcec4232b18ad/tensorflow/core/framework/rendezvous.h#L30) interface, which has multiple different implementations, depending on the deployment. The comment on that interface describes the general idea:

```
// A Rendezvous is an abstraction for passing a Tensor
// from a producer to a consumer, where the consumer may safely
// request the Tensor before or after it has been produced.  A
// producer never blocks when using a Rendezvous.  A consumer has the
// choice of making a blocking call or providing a callback: in either
// case, the consumer receives the Tensor as soon as it is available.
```

As you noted in your question, TensorFlow represents communication in the dataflow graph using `Send` and `Recv` ops that are added to the graph automatically when the graph is partitioned across devices. For each edge that has a source and destination on different devices, the graph partitioner inserts a pair of `Send` and `Recv` ops that share the same "rendezvous key" (an automatically generated string name that is used as a key in the rendezvous' index of pending tensors to be communicated). The [implementation of the `Send` op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41285cf7a11fa3a2c2ead6b6e9adcec4232b18ad/tensorflow/core/kernels/sendrecv_ops.cc#L57) is simple: it calls `Rendezvous::Send()`, passing in its rendezvous key and single input tensor, then returns immediately without blocking. The [implementation of the `Recv` op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41285cf7a11fa3a2c2ead6b6e9adcec4232b18ad/tensorflow/core/kernels/sendrecv_ops.cc#L106) is slightly more complicated: it registers a callback to be called when the tensor with the given key becomes available. That [callback](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41285cf7a11fa3a2c2ead6b6e9adcec4232b18ad/tensorflow/core/kernels/sendrecv_ops.cc#L120) is responsible for "producing" the output of the `Recv` op, and unblocking subsequent computation.

The `Rendezvous` implementations perform the actual work of transferring the data:

- [`IntraProcessRendezvous`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41285cf7a11fa3a2c2ead6b6e9adcec4232b18ad/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/rendezvous_mgr.h#L32) handles the transfer of data between devices in the same process. In the (unlikely) event that the transfer is between two CPU devices in the same process, the transfer can be achieved by a [simple `Tensor` assignment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41285cf7a11fa3a2c2ead6b6e9adcec4232b18ad/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/rendezvous_mgr.cc#L73). Otherwise, TensorFlow [kicks off](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41285cf7a11fa3a2c2ead6b6e9adcec4232b18ad/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/rendezvous_mgr.cc#L106) a device-specific DMA routine to transfer data between a CPU and GPU device.
- The [`BaseRemoteRendezvous`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41285cf7a11fa3a2c2ead6b6e9adcec4232b18ad/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/base_rendezvous_mgr.h#L108) class and its subclasses handle cross-device communication in the case that the send and receiver can be in different processes. The main implementation of this class is [`RpcRemoteRendezvous`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41285cf7a11fa3a2c2ead6b6e9adcec4232b18ad/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/rpc_rendezvous_mgr.cc#L39), which [uses gRPC](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/41285cf7a11fa3a2c2ead6b6e9adcec4232b18ad/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/rpc_rendezvous_mgr.cc#L266) to handle the remote transfers.

Comment: @mrry Very specific instruction

Comment: Hi @mrry, do you know how to utilize Rendezvous to transfer tensor between two machines? I tried with customized op and `tf.raw_ops.Send/Recv`, but none of these successfully transferred tensor between two machines. Please see [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47257](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47257) and [https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47277](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/47277).