# Tensorflow Communication Cross CPU to Multi GPUs

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

From the tensorflow white paper and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40710224/tensorflow-cross-device-communication/40711279#40711279) from @mrry, tensorFlow adds `Send/Recv` ops to copy data cross device boundaries, and uses `Rendezvous` to do the actual work. The communication method cross different devices in tensorflow is `noblocking send, blocking recv`.

It seems (please correct me if wrong) after reading, parsing and batching from the input data queue, the batch examples will be sent from CPU to GPU if I use GPU to train.

1. I want to know when use multi GPU, the batch examples in CPU are how to send to multi GPUs? Is there several `Send` ops in CPU, each of which is match to one GPU, and each GPU get one batch_size example? or there is only one `Send` op in CPU?
2. From the document  [config.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/26b4dfa65d360f2793ad75083c797d57f8661b93/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L170), `inter_op_parallelism_threads` option configure a thread pool in parallel execution, as the comments describe:

   > // Nodes that perform blocking operations are enqueued on a pool of
   >   // inter_op_parallelism_threads available in each process.

Is it means blocking operations `Recv` can be done in multi-threads when `inter_op_parallelism_threads` option is set?

If the description of the questions is unclear, please ask me further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of tensorflow after looking into the source code a bit deeper:

1. There'are multiple send / recv ops. Since the send / recv op pairs are created for each cross-device edge.
2. Recv is an async-op which will never block the execution. The `done` callback will be called when data is ready for the recv op.